# Is it possible to add the syntax highlight of other programming languages on the template node on Node-RED?

Tags: node-red

Using a `function` node on Node-RED, we can create a function that executes a piece of code in any other programming language stored on the `template` node. I've created a node that basically compiles and executes a `c++` code that is stored on the `template` node all the times that there are changes on it. It works as follows:

[image]

However, the `template` node doesn't support the syntax of C++. Using the python one is good while I don't have any comments on the code and the Javascript one works for comments but it indicates errors on all lines because it's expecting Javascript code. Is it possible to include the **syntax highlight** of other programming languages besides the default ones on the `template` node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [hardillb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59527855/4572853)'s answer and [this issue](https://discourse.nodered.org/t/more-languages-supported-syntax-highlighting-in-template-nodes/15041) on the official Node-RED forum, I've figured out how to include a different type of syntax highlight for the `template` node. Basically, we need to do four things:

1. Find the location of the HTML file that creates the template node on the system. On Linux, it's located on `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/@node-red/nodes/core/function/80-template.html`
2. Inside the file `80-template.html`, find the following block of code and add the extra syntax options that you need (in this example I've added `C++` and `Java`):

   ```
   <select id="node-input-format" style="width:110px; font-size: 10px !important;  height: 24px; padding:0;">
       <option value="handlebars">mustache</option>
       <option value="html">HTML</option>
       <option value="json">JSON</option>
       <option value="javascript">Javascript</option>
       <option value="css">CSS</option>
       <option value="markdown">Markdown</option>
       <option value="python">Python</option>
       <option value="sql">SQL</option>
       <option value="yaml">YAML</option>
       <option value="c_cpp">C++</option>
       <option value="java">Java</option>
       <option value="text" data-i18n="template.label.none"></option>
   </select>
   ```
3. On [this GitHub page](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/tree/master/src-min-noconflict) of the Ace Editor, download a `mode-desiredLanguage` file and copy it to `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/@node-red/editor-client/public/vendor/ace`. In my case, I've downloaded both `mode-c_cpp.js` and `mode-java.js`...
4. Restart the service that is running Node-RED and reloads its page on the browser.

---

**Final Result**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The editor used by Node-RED is the [Ace](https://ace.c9.io/) component. While this can support many different languages iirc the included list is limited to help keep the Node-RED package size down to a sensible size.

I know that people have asked about support for different languages in the past on either the Node-RED Slack team or on the Forum (both of which are linked from the Node-RED homepage). It may be worth searching the forum or asking on Slack.